# The referenced column name has to be a primary key column on the target entity class

Tags: php, mysql, linux, doctrine-orm, doctrine

everyone. Happy new year! Today I am having problems trying to resolving this problem:

> Could not resolve type of column "id_usuario" of class "FacturadorVirtual\Modelos\Seguridad\Usuario"

For some, this error is only present in linux enviroment. In windows, no problem. What the problem is exactly? Looks like `PlanAdquirido` is not finding the column `id_usuario` through the relationship `$adquiridoPor`. Again: this error is only triggered in linux enviroment.

Usuario entity:

```
<?php

namespace FacturadorVirtual\Modelos\Seguridad;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

/**
 * @entity
 * @table(name="usuarios")
 */
class Usuario implements Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * @id
     * @var integer
     * @column(type="integer", name="id_usuario")
     * @generatedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

PlanAdquirido entity:

```
<?php

namespace FacturadorVirtual\Modelos\Planes;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use FacturadorVirtual\Modelos\Seguridad\Usuario;

/**
 * @entity
 * @table(name="planes_adquiridos")
 */
class PlanAdquirido
{
    /**
     * @id
     * @var integer
     * @column(type="integer", name="id_plan")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Usuario
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="FacturadorVirtual\Modelos\Seguridad\Usuario")
     * @JoinColumn(name="adquirido_por", referencedColumnName="id_usuario")
     */
    protected $adquiridoPor;

}
```

If I run `"vendor/bin/doctrine.bat" orm:validate-schema` in windows I get:

```
Mapping
-------
[OK] The mapping files are correct.
```

But in linux I get:

```
Mapping
-------
 [FAIL] The entity-class FacturadorVirtual\Modelos\Planes\PlanAdquirido mapping is invalid:
 * The referenced column name 'id_plan' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'FacturadorVirtual\Modelos\Planes\PlanAdquirido'.
 * The referenced column name 'id_usuario' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'FacturadorVirtual\Modelos\Seguridad\Usuario'.
```

> Column name `id_usuario` referenced for relation from FacturadorVirtual\Modelos\Planes\PlanAdquirido towards FacturadorVirtual\Modelos\Seguridad\Usuario does not exist.

I do not know if I am missing something, but have I have two days trying to figure out why is not working in linux (where production will reside).

- Tables and column's name are all in lower case, using MySQL 5.7

Comment: Just for grins, try '@Id' instead of '@id'.  Linux does tend to be more case sensitive.  Same for other annotations like '@Column'. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys

Comment: @Cerad, the problem persists

Comment: Is the version of MySQL the same in the two environments?

Comment: @Jerry, the db is the same, because it is hosted in a dedicated server, both environments target same db machine.

Comment: Could you change your line @JoinColumn(name="adquirido_por", referencedColumnName="id_usuario") to this: @JoinColumn(name="adquirido_por", referencedColumnName="id") and try?

Comment: If that doesn't work, please paste your SQL structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I found the answer. The problem was redi's cache. Everytime the project was updated I ran the clear cache command:

```
"vendor/bin/doctrine" orm:clear-cache:metadata
```

I thought that this command already cleared the cache, but it did not. To clear the cache correcly just run:

```
$ redis-cli
> flushall
```

All works great now since then!